# Что известно о происхождении слова "обсервация"?

Tags: этимология

Термином *обсервация* в астрономии называют наблюдение за космическими объектами. Этим же словом медики называют наблюдение за временно изолированными здоровыми людьми, которые могли иметь контакт с больными.
Слово обозревать имеет тот же смысл, что и наблюдать, да и звучит оно почти так же как обсервация.

Существует ли на самом деле связь между словами *обозревать* и *обсервация* или все совпадения случайны?

Answer (score 3):

**ОБСЕРВАЦИЯ,**  ж. [лат. observation] 1. Мед. **Наблюдение за временно изолированными людьми,** прибывающими из мест эпидемий для выявления случаев заболевания и необходимой профилактики.  2. Мор. **Наблюдение за береговыми объектами и светилами** для определения географических координат судна на море.

**ОБОЗРЕТЬ**,  св. что. 1. Окинуть взором, осмотреть.

Обычно о родственных исторических связях  слов можно сделать окончательный вывод, если сравнить  их **индоевропейские основы**. Вот и попробуем это сделать.

**1) Обсервация**

Обсерва́ция «наблюдение», впервые в Уст. морск. 1720 г.; см. Смирнов 208 и сл. Через польск. obserwacja или нем. Observation (с ХVI в.; см. Шульц-Баслер 2, 228 и сл.) из лат. **observātiō**. Происхождение слова *обсервация* в этимологическом онлайн-словаре **Фасмера М.**

**Викисловарь:** От лат. observatio «наблюдение», от гл. observare «**следить, наблюдать**», далее из ob «к, против, перед» + servāre «**сторожить, охранять**», из праиндоевр. ***ser- «защищать».**

Можно отметить,что слова ***обсервация***  и ***сервис*** исторически родственные. Сервис – это служба для охраны и наблюдения, а потом просто служба, обслуживание.

**Итак, и.-е. корень ser.**

**2) Обозревать**

***Зреть*** (из словаря П. Черных): О.-с. основа, **zьreti**, и.-е. корень **gher** – сиять, сверкать, блистать, тот же корень в словах *заря* и *зоркий*.

**Вывод:** слова  ***обсервация*** и ***обозревать*** не являются исторически  родственными,  **они сближены** на следующей основе:  **наблюдать** (сторожить, следить) и **наблюдать** с помощью зрения.

Answer (score 2):

Обсерва́ция произошло от лат. observatio - наблюдение.

Обозревать и наблюдать - разные по смыслу слова, объединены они только тематической группой "смотреть, зрение".

Большой толковый словарь:

> НАБЛЮДАТЬ
>
> 1. кого-что, за кем-чем или с придат.
>      дополнит. Внимательно следить. Н. за полётом самолёта, за космическим
>      объектом. Н. солнечное затмение. Н., как сын рисует картину. Н. за
>      пешеходами.
> 2. Видеть, замечать, встречать. Вы наблюдали
>      когда-нибудь альбиносов. Такой ранней зимы не наблюдали много лет.
>      Врачи наблюдали потерю памяти после контузии.
> 3. кого-что. Изучать,
>      исследовать. Н. больного. Н. жизнь животных.
> 4. за кем-чем.
>      Осуществлять надзор, наблюдение за кем-, чем-л. Н. за детьми. Н. за
>      порядком. <Наблюдаться, -ается; страд. (3 зн.). Наблюдение (см.).

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Словарь Ефремовой:

> Обозревать
>
> 1. Окидывать взором, осматривать открывшееся взору.
> 2. Осматривать что-л. для ознакомления или проверки.
> 3. перен. Анализировать, рассматривая что-л. в совокупности признаков.
> 4. разг. Делать обзор чего-л., излагая в речи, статье.

https://znachenie-slova.ru/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Обсервация  — это всё-таки **наблюдение**. Наблюдение астрономического объекта;

наблюдение за изолированными в специальном помещении здоровыми людьми, которые могли иметь контакт с заболевшими карантинными болезнями;

наблюдение за внешними ориентирами, чтобы определить местоположение корабля , судна и т. д.

В обсервациях не обозревают людей, а наблюдают за ними. Чем-то слова обсервация и обозрение похожи, но это простое совпадение.